# How is VSCode finding this Go linting Problem and how do I ignore it?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

I'm setting up linting with `golangci-lint` in my Go project. I have a file generated by `go-bindata` that VSCode is listing the following under the Problems tab:

> assets/assets.go: redundant type from array, slice, or map composite literal (simplifycompositelit)

I can't seem to get rid of it. It's not a compiler error and I'll be re-running `go-bindata` from time to time so I don't want to make a habit of modifying generated code.

Right now, with the configuration below, I can't make VSCode stop reporting this error. If I run `golangci-lint run ./...` in the root of the workspace I get no output. I can provide my linting config if needed but VSCode seems to be running something else. How do I figure out what's reporting this error and how do I make it stop reporting anything for the file `assets/assets.go` in this one workspace?

Here's Go-related vscode settings:

```
{
  "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
  "go.lintTool": "golangci-lint",
  "go.liveErrors": {
    "enabled": true,
    "delay": 500
  },
  "go.lintOnSave": "workspace",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
  "go.useLanguageServer": true,
  "go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures": {
    "diagnostics": true,
    "documentLink": true
  },
}
```

Here's the line in question even with a nolint comment to show it's not behaving as expected. If it were golangci-lint outputting this, the nolint would prevent the warning from showing. I reloaded the window and closed/reopened vscode to be sure the change was noticed.

[image: picture of the source where the linter is making this warning]

Comment: I'm running `go-bindata -o assets/assets.go -pkg assets -debug -prefix embedded/ embedded/` with the latest go-bindata in a go:generate to build the file. It seems you have to include at least one file for the linting error to be generated in. That's the code that the mystery linter is complaining about.

Comment: Which `go-bindata` fork are you using? There are many, with slight differences.

Comment: github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing locally, it seems this message comes from `gopls`, as disabling `gopls` silences the message. There are a couple of related complaints/issues on the Go issue tracker:

- <strike>[hide gofmt -s diagnostics (and others?) in generated files](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38467)</strike>
- [should not issue lint-style warnings on generated code](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41436)

Neither offers an actual solution.

However, [this issue](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/227) on the `vscode-go` repo, provides a work-around. In your VSCode config, add the `gopls.analyses.simplifycompositelit` key, with a value of `false`:

```json
    "gopls": {
        "analyses": {
            "simplifycompositelit": false
        },
    }
```

Of course, this disables it for all projects, not just generated files, but if you're also using `golangci-lint`, it can be configured to catch the same types of errors, and can be configured on a more granular basis, so that you won't miss the same class of errors in non-generated code.